# HTML entities are being displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, tooltips

On [this page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/93083/front-end-engineer-feedzai) if you hover the mouse on the photos under "**Who you’ll work with you**" you'll notice the HTML entities are displayed:

> [image]

i.e.:

Andr`&#233;` Prata
instead of:
André Prata

Is this a bug ?

Comment: Repro-ed in IE11/Win7 and Chrome/Win7

Comment: @rene yeah, this is most likely encoded in the server side. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I assumed that but you never know with Internet Explorer ...

Comment: Yup, bug. We'll look into it shortly.

Answer (score 5):

This was a small bug with a data sync job which reads from SQL Server and writes to a JSON blob - effectively, the name got HTML-encoded twice.

Should be fixed.

Comment: I just checked and it looks the same as before  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/93083/front-end-engineer-feedzai

Comment: Ah, you're right - it's fixed on the company page but didn't sync to the job listing yet. There's a task running every few minutes to sync it but I probably can trigger it manually, stand by..

Comment: It's actually cached and should update within the next hour or so. I'm too scared to mess with the Redis cache directly. :)

Comment: Go it, I'll check it later!

Comment: One hour passed and it's still there. That cache is stubborn... :)

Comment: Stubborn indeed! Will have another look this afternoon.

Comment: Three hours and still no cigar... looking forward to your afternoon. (here it's evening by now :))

Comment: Needed another nudge, fixed on both the company page and job listing now.

Comment: It seems fixed !

Comment: Any chance your nudge caused [something else to break](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267104/why-the-most-recent-search-is-not-sorted-by-date)? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, unrelated but possibly similar. :)

Comment: @Max I blame caching ;)

Answer (score 3):

I check `<meta>` tags on the Page you mentioned.

```
<meta property="og:title" content=" Front-end Engineer at Feedzai" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Feedzai is a startup with offices in Portugal and Silicon Valley building a groundbreaking product for online fraud prevention and digital payments. Keeping up…" />
<meta property="og:image" content="//cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Img/logos/favicon-152x152.png?v=b906110d24f0" />
<meta name="Description" content="Feedzai is a startup with offices in Portugal and Silicon Valley building a groundbreaking product for online fraud prevention and digital payments. Keeping up…" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@StackDevJobs">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="Stack Overflow Careers">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Front-end Engineer at Feedzai">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Feedzai is a startup with offices in Portugal and Silicon Valley building a groundbreaking product for online fraud prevention and digital payments. Keeping up with the company growth, Feedzai is…">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN7Mx.jpg">
```

They are **missing**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

That is not problem in your Browser. Problem is with  data entered or in database

---

Check this. (below code with there output)

1. `&amp;#233;` - Out put `&amp;#233;`
2. `&#233;` - output **é**

**Solution**

1. Correct the database field
2. Change `&amp;#233;` to `e&#769;`// output **é**

Comment: Appreciate the effort, you were very close. :) The data was actually correct in the database but then got HTML-encoded twice instead of just once.