# Why the most recent search is not sorted by date?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, sorting

Is there any problem with the most recent search in "[Job Listing - Stack Overflow Careers page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?f=t&sort=p)".  In the past this looked Ok to me but from yesterday the listings or not sorted by date (descending) i.e most recent job postings does not appear at the top. Is this is an issue or I am missing out some thing here?

[image]

Comment: Weird, when searching for something, the [sort appears to be fine](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java&sort=p). I suspect something went wrong with some server side caching, that cached the wrong results.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmmm, that was me :/

I was refactoring a bunch of search code and used the wrong variable when building the query we throw at our Elastic servers so the scoring functions for 'Most Recent' weren't being used. I just pushed a fix to production.

Thanks for the report!